# Would second order variation necessary for the calculation of the area?

Tags: analysis, calculus-of-variations

In physics people do the variation of a quantity typically of the form
$$
\delta_X f(X,Y,Z)=0
$$
where in general the variation
$$X\rightarrow X+\delta X $$ where $$\delta X\propto \epsilon g(X) $$
of some small variable $\epsilon$ and only the first order variation was considered.
However, it seemed that the quality of the interest through this procedure were mostly first order, by which I mean at most a line integral
$$\int dX \text{(the quantity of the interest)} $$
or if a transformation was required
$$H(X,Y,Z)\rightarrow H(\tilde X, Y,Z) +\Delta X  T(X,Y,Z)$$

However, what if the quantity of the interest was of the second order in nature? i.e.
$$f(X,Y,Z)=\int dX \int dX... $$ and
$$\int dX \int dX \text{(the quantity of the interest)}$$

Would the second order variation necessary to be kept under this situation?